# Changing the locations shown on the side of the 'open' panel

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-explorer, file-management

Sometimes, when accessing documents from within programs on Windows, you have this popup:

[image: image of dialog]

**How can I change the locations that appear on the left side of this popup?**

(I say sometimes because other times you have a slightly different popup with more easily customisable options displayed as a list.)

(I'm running Win8 (hence [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8), but I realise the solution may be cross-compatible, so I've also tagged [windows](/questions/tagged/windows).)

Comment: Are you asking this for an application you're developing, or in general?

Comment: @Rowland In general, as a user, not developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a tool: [TweakUI](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/tweakui.htm). It works in Windows XP.

As far as I know there was no such tool developed for Vista/7/8.
I'm quite sure this compatibility mode Open/Save dialog can be customized in Vista+ by changing the same registry values.

1. Start Registry Editor: <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, `regedit`.
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies`.
3. With `Policies` selected, right-click on empty space in the right pane, and point at **New**, then click **Key**. And type `comdlg32`.
4. Similarly, with `comdlg32` selected, create new `Placesbar` key.
5. You can create up to five places – `Place0`, `Place1` .. `Place4` – in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\comdlg32\Placesbar`:

   1. Right-click on empty space in the right pane, point at **New**, and click **String value**.
   2. Type the name: `Place0`.
   3. Double-click `Place0` and type the value: the path to a directory which will be displayed as the first place on the bar.

<sub>[Source](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/4-more-ways-to-customize-common-dialog-open-in-windows-xp/)</sub>

---

What version of the dialog you would see depends on the programmer or rather the tools programmer used. Usually applications targeted to Windows XP have this kind of Open/Save dialog.

<sub>If you need more info, I can give more details, however programming part of it belong [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).</sub>

Comment: Editing the registry worked a treat. I didn't even have to restart. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 1):

That dialog is an ancient one from XP times. The current Open File Dialog looks like this:

[image]

which has at the very top of the bar a “Favourites” section where you can put what you like.

Alas, you'd have to get the application you're using to use the current dialog instead of the old one (and some toolkits/frameworks, e.g. Java or GTK, even insist on redoing the dialog completely, moving further and further from what is usually used on the system).