# (Virtual) Path to My Computer

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-registry, shortcuts

I've been doing a [bit of registry editing](https://superuser.com/questions/499571/changing-the-locations-shown-on-the-side-of-the-open-panel). As you can see (the accepted answer), each of five keys in the registry points to a location. This works fine with normal directories.

However, `My Computer` isn't a physical location, so **how can I link to it like I could a normal directory?**

I thought maybe the registry could point to a shortcut to `My Computer`, but Windows 8 won't allow me to point a shortcut there. (The `Ok` option is greyed out on the new shortcut wizard when `My Computer` is selected.)

<sub>(This may be applicable to other versions of windows; hence the double tagging.)</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a directory and name it

```
My Computer.{20d04fe0-3aea-1069-a2d8-08002b30309d}
```

Shell paths, such as My Computer, have a [GUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID) and this is a way of creating a link to such a path that has no representation in the file system.

Comment: Can you explain what this does? Is that a memory address?

Answer (score 2):

From my analysis *My Computer* can be represented by the registry key ::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}